# Get the balance of my users in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Help please, I have a table like this:

```
 | ID | userId   | amount  | type    |
 -------------------------------------
 |  1 |       10 |  10     | expense |
 |  2 |       10 |  22     | income  |
 |  3 |        3 |  25     | expense |
 |  4 |        3 |  40     | expense |
 |  5 |        3 |  63     | income  |
```

I'm looking for a way to use one query and retrive the balance of each user.

The hard part comes when the amounts has to be added on expenses and substracted on incomes.

This would be the result table:

```
 | userId | balance |
 --------------------
 |   10   |  12     |
 |    3   |  -2     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easiest to do with a single group by:

```
select user_id,
       sum(case when type = 'income' then amount else - amount end) as balance
from t
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to get each totals of `income` and `expense` using ***subquery*** then later on ***join*** them so you can `subtract expense from income`

```
SELECT  a.UserID,
        (b.totalIncome - a.totalExpense) `balance`
FROM
(
    SELECT  userID, SUM(amount) totalExpense
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   type = 'expense'
    GROUP BY userID
) a INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  userID, SUM(amount) totalIncome
    FROM    myTable
    WHERE   type = 'income'
    GROUP BY userID
) b on a.userID = b.userid
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bc18/1)

Comment: This query actually will not work for a user that has only income or only expenses.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 sub-queries, each grouped by id: one sums the incomes, the other the expenses.  Then you could join these together, so that each row had an id, the sum of the expenses and the sum of the income(s), from which you can easily compute the balance.